# Diagonal upright text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to label a diagonal line in Tikz so that the text runs diagonally yet is upright. My use case is just a row of small 1's for a triangular matrix, but something flexible is preferred. Something like just drawing a dashed line, but instead of dashes or dots its small 1's/numbers/letters that are upright.

I would think that this has been done before, but my google kungfu didn't manage it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please add a small, compilable document which can form the basis of a solution. (A Minimum Working Example or MWE.) This makes it a lot easier (and more fun) for people to help you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [-latex, blue, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (20:2.5cm);
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10} { 
        \node  [above] at (20:0.2*\x cm) {1};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found I needed more control than Peter Grill's answer (which did what I asked), so I'm just leaving this here for others. It requires the decorations tikz option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.marking}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) at (0,0) {A};
        \node (b) at (2,2) {B};

        \path [postaction = {decorate, decoration = 
            {markings, mark = between positions 0.0 and 1 step 0.2 with 
                {\node[font=\tiny]{1};}}}] (a) -- (b)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: diagonal 1's from (a) to (b)]

Comment: nice... I like your answer.